# Inserting multiple records based on select and check records exists + Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have created a sql query as seen below. Basically I need to achieve two things.
1. Insert record only if the correlationid doesnt exist in correlationmessage table.
2. Insert two records one with MessageTypeId = 1 and MessageTypeId = 2.

I have tried and achieved the second one but dont know how to do the first one

```
insert into MESSAGING.CorrelationMessage 
       (CorrelationId, MessageTypeId, RequestMessage,ResponseMessage, IsMatched, CreatedDate)
(
    Select ActivityID, 1 as MessageTypeId, NULL as RequestMessage, NULL as ResponseMessage, 1 as IsMatched, GETDATE() as CreatedDate  
    from account.Activity a
    join account.ActivityType b on b.ActivityTypeID=a.ActivityTypeID
    join ACCOUNT.TransactionType c on c.TransactionTypeID=a.TransactionTypeID
    where a.ActivityTypeID=3
    and ExecutingBroker is null
    and a.active=1 
    and TradeDate is null
    and DateforGTDOrders > GETDATE()

    union

    Select ActivityID, 2 as MessageTypeId, NULL as RequestMessage, NULL as ResponseMessage, 1 as IsMatched, GETDATE() as CreatedDate  
    from account.Activity a
    join account.ActivityType b on b.ActivityTypeID=a.ActivityTypeID
    join ACCOUNT.TransactionType c on c.TransactionTypeID=a.TransactionTypeID
    where a.ActivityTypeID=3
    and ExecutingBroker is null
    and a.active=1 
    and TradeDate is null
    and DateforGTDOrders > GETDATE()
)
```

This query is a bit different as it to doing multiple inserts based on select as also checking if the record exists. Since it is a union it is quite tricky to do the check.

Comment: This is bit different

Comment: Just put a not exists on each select - see duplicate

Comment: If the duplicate did not help you reach an answer, can you edit your question to explain why the same technique cannot be used in your case?   Why does a union make it tricky to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With in your insert, you can:

```
select * from
(Select ActivityID,1 as MessageTypeId,NULL as RequestMessage  ,NULL as ResponseMessage,1 as IsMatched ,GETDATE() as CreatedDate  from account.Activity a
join account.ActivityType b on b.ActivityTypeID=a.ActivityTypeID
join ACCOUNT.TransactionType c on c.TransactionTypeID=a.TransactionTypeID
where a.ActivityTypeID=3
and ExecutingBroker is null
and a.active=1 
and TradeDate is null
and DateforGTDOrders > GETDATE()
union
Select ActivityID,2 as MessageTypeId,NULL as RequestMessage  ,NULL as ResponseMessage,1 as IsMatched ,GETDATE() as CreatedDate  from account.Activity a
join account.ActivityType b on b.ActivityTypeID=a.ActivityTypeID
join ACCOUNT.TransactionType c on c.TransactionTypeID=a.TransactionTypeID
where a.ActivityTypeID=3
and ExecutingBroker is null
and a.active=1 
and TradeDate is null
and DateforGTDOrders > GETDATE()) ab
where not exits ( select 1 from MESSAGING.CorrelationMessage a where a.CorrelationId = ab.CorrelationId and ab.MessageTypeId = a.MessageTypeId)
```

I have not tried this query but please give it a shot, I know this would not be most optimized way to do it. But, you would need to tune it. This is just an idea.

Comment: here is small correction to the where not exists clause. It is  a.CorrelationId = ab.ActivityID . I get the following Error converting data type varchar to bigint. if i modify the query to where not exists ( select 1 from MESSAGING.CorrelationMessage a where (N'a.CorrelationId') = (N'ab.ActivityID')) . it shows me record in message table thought it exist